# Find the total heat in the bar given the following initial temperature distribution

Tags: calculus, integration, heat-equation

Consider a fully insulated (both laterally and on the ends) bar of length L, that has been heated to an initial temperature distribution of $-x(x-L)$. Find the total heat in the bar for all time.

Above is my problem statement. Here is what I have gathered:

- The bar is fully insulated, so not heat can enter nor escape the system, other than the initial temperature.
- The initial temperature distribution implies zero degrees on the ends of the bar and maximum temperature in the centre.
- Putting the two together, I assume that the bar will eventually come to a non-zero uniform, constant temperature.

So, am I correct to say that the total heat is simply the integral of $-x(x-L)$ for $0$ to $L$, or am I missing something?

Comment: Sounds reasonable. The total heat is constant in time, and can be found from the initial conditions as you described. Unless some physical details like density were provided, feel free to ignore the heat/temperature distinction pointed out in the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your bullet points look good. Heat and temperature are different physical quantities, though.

We're given a temperature distribution $T(x)=-x(x-L)$. Integrating temperature for one dimension of length gives you units of $temperature \times length$. That doesn't quite match up to heat, which has units of $energy$.

Heat, $Q$, is related to temperature as $Q=mc T$ where $m$ is the mass and $c$ is the specific heat of the material. Mass depends on the length, $m=\lambda L$ where for a rod, $\lambda$ is the mass density per unit length. The density could be a constant but doesn't have to be, so in general $\lambda = \lambda (x)$. Specific heat $c$ also needn't be a constant, so $c=c(x)$. In general then,

$$Q= mcT=\int_0^L \lambda (x)c(x)T(x) dx= \int_0^L \lambda c\big(-x(x-L)\ \big) dx$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Let $\rho$ be the linear mass density & $c$ be the specific heat of the bar then consider a bar element of length $dx$

The total heat in the bar $$=\int_{0}^{L} c\ dm T_x=\int_{0}^{L} c(\rho dx) T_x=\rho c\int_{0}^{L}T_x\ dx$$ 
Put the value of the temperature distribution function $T_x$